# Why does Angularjs hate my while loop?

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

this is my first time posting, fyi. I am trying to make a button that makes a pdf file. The PDF button works if I just add simple text. Also, the `i<myData.length` alert works just fine, but when the code gets to the while loop, it immediately goes to an angularjs exception handler. Any thoughts?

```
$scope.makePDF = function () {
    //window.alert($scope.myData.length);
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 30, "Table");
    var i = 0;
    window.alert(i < $scope.myData.length);
    while (i < $scope.myData.length) {
        window.alert(i < $scope.myData.length);
        doc.text(20, 40, $scope.myData[i]["pit"] + "-" + $scope.myData[i]["game"] + "-" + $scope.myData[i]["table"]);
        i++;
        var isTrue = i < scope.myData.length;
    }


    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('Test.pdf');


};
```

Here is the error output I get. To be honest, I don't get much from it. If anyone could understand more from it that would be great (also, stackoverflow made me take out the links):

ReferenceError: scope is not defined

```
   at Scope.$scope.makePDF 
    at angular.js:9943:21
    at angular.js:17611:17
    at Scope.$eval angular.js:11634:28
    at Scope.$apply angular.js:11734:23
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> angular.js:17610:21
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074:9
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle jquery-1.9.1.js:2750:46 angular.js:9159
(anonymous function) angular.js:9159
(anonymous function) angular.js:6751
Scope.$apply angular.js:11736
(anonymous function) angular.js:17610
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle
```

Comment: Very unlikely to be the issue related to Angular

Comment: plz, show the error output.

Comment: The error should be reported in the browser's console. Did you check it out?.

Comment: Errors have been added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first site you seem to be accessing the second dimension of a multi dimension array with a string value. Not certain that will work.

If myData is an array of objects then you need something like

```
myData[i].pit
```

If it is a two dimensional array then you need `myData[i][j]` where i and j are zero based indexers into your array.